# How to delete table in Excel but preserve comments using VSTO?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I'm using the snippet below to convert an Excel range with data into a table. In some cases, I need to delete the table, but preserve comments in the cells. Is there a way I can achieve that? Also, is there a way to toggle the headers on/off? I tried the different options under `XlListObjectHasHeaders: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess.` but those didn't work. thanks for your help.

```
finalRange.Worksheet.ListObjects.AddEx(
SourceType: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
Source: finalRange,
XlListObjectHasHeaders: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
```

I delete the table structure like this -

```
finalRange.Worksheet.ListObjects.Item[1].Delete();
```

EDIT (solution for multiple tables):

```
        foreach (var table in sheet.ListObjects)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject tempObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObject)table;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range tempRange = tempObj.Range;
            tempRange.ClearContents();        
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These both presuppose your Table variable is `lo`:

```
Excel.ListObject lo = ws.ListObjects["Table1"];
```

To hide the header row in an Excel table:

```
lo.ShowHeaders = false;
```

To Remove the table but retain the comments, use the `range.Clear` method instead of the `table.Delete`.

```
Excel.Range tableRange = lo.Range;
tableRange.ClearContents();
```

Comment: This works, however what if I'm dealing with multiple tables in a sheet? What would I use instead of `Excel.ListObject lo = ws.ListObjects["Table1"];` to access them all... lets say to delete them?

Comment: Also, is `Table1` a predefined name? Can I name the tables myself during declaration so I can access them easily?

Comment: If you want all tables, you can iterate them all with `ws.ListObjects`.  If that's not clear, let me know, and I can update my answer.

Comment: If you want to delete them, another way of doing this is to convert them to ranges and then clear the data -- this will clobber any existence of the Tables but retain the comments (and formatting, if you want it, although you can delete that pretty easily).  Again let me know if it's not clear.

Comment: ^ that is exactly what I was just trying. Pls check my edit. I want to essentially remove the tables and preserve the comments when I have the need to. The snippet above isn't working because it cannot convert `table` to an `ListObject`

Comment: It finally works. Thank you so much for all your help. I am able to remove the tables and preserve the comments.

Comment: 1 final question, assuming my sheet has multiple tables, how can i set the headers on and off for individual tables when I create them? I'm guessing I can't use `Excel.ListObject lo = ws.ListObjects["Table1"];`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the indexer on `ListObjects` works the same way as `WorkSheets`, in that you can reference it by the name or by the number.  So, as you create Tables, the first is ListObjects[1], the second is [2] and so on.  They do start with 1, not 0.  If you create the Table within C#, you can just hang onto that object and then change the `ShowHeaders` property.